# How to remove zero values from an array in parallel

Tags: c++, arrays, cuda, thrust

How can I efficiently remove zero values from an array in parallel using CUDA. 
The information about the number of zero values is available in advance, 
which should simplify this task.

It is important that the numbers remain ordered as in the source array,
when being copied to the resulting array.

---

Example:

The array would e.g. contain the following values:
[0, 0, 19, 7, 0, 3, 5, 0, 0, 1] 
with the additional information that 5 values are zeros.
The desired end result would then be another array containing:
[19, 7, 3, 5, 1]

Comment: surely you want to remove zeros? if you remove the non zeros you would get an array of only zeros?!

Comment: yeah corrected that. I am looking for an efficient way to remove the zero values from the source array.

Comment: I would like to replace the for loop through cuda threads, effectivly parallelizing the removal.

Comment: This sounds like a standard stream stream compaction operation

Comment: When searching for algorithmic approaches, this is definitely right. Thx for your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To eliminate some elements from an array you may use [Thrust Library's reordering operations](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/index.html#reordering). Given a predicate `is_not_zero`, which returns `false` for zero values, and `true` for others, you may write the operation like this

```
thrust::copy_if(in_array, in_array + size, out_array, is_not_zero);
```

the output array will include only the values which are non-zero, because the predicate indicates so.

You may also use "remove_if" function with a reverse predicate which return `true` for zeros, and `false` for others..

```
thrust::remove_if(in_array, in_array + size, is_zero);
```

I suggest you taking a look at compaction examples of Thrust library, or general compaction concept.

https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/stream_compaction.cu

Comment: I might not be able to use thrust in that project, but if I could I would use your proposal. Thx for your help.

Comment: There are similar libraries and just kernel implementations for compaction. You might not need to use Thrust for just this function, I suggest you to use it though. Just look at the examples of CUDA SDK.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use Thrust and you prefer to use CUDA, probably the best thing to do is to run Sum Scan, described in detail here

https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/gpugems2/part-iv-general-purpose-computation-gpus-primer/chapter-36-stream-reduction

Answer (score 1):

What about a variation of odd-even merge sort, or in fact any sorting algorithm, where the ordering is defined by `a < b === (a != 0 && b == 0)`?

Comment: This is a one-bit sort, so one can do a lot better than a general merge sort.

Comment: @JaredHoberock: Well, I have not seen you propose a different working approach that works a lot better.

Comment: Another problem with a sorting approach is that it would destroy the input, which @diver_182 wishes to preserve in the input array. `remove_copy_if` will work better for this case as @phoad notes above.

Comment: @JaredHoberock: That's not a problem, he can first copy and then sort.